# Error displaying in "Guess my number" game

Tags: c

I am learning C programming and now I am trying to code this program called "Guess my number" whereby player 1 will pick a number in a range, and then player 2 will guess the number. If the number of guesses exceed 10 tries, player 1 will win. However, the code program breaks after 10 tries and does not display the "Player 1 wins". Anybody can help me in this? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define boolean

int main()
{

    int enternumber = -1;
    int count = 0;
    int maxguesses = 10;
    int guessing;
    int i;
    bool currentguesses = false;


    while (1) {
        count += 1;
        printf("Player 1, enter a number between 1 and 1000\n");
        scanf("%d", &enternumber);

        if (enternumber > 1000) {
            printf("That number is out of range\n");
        }

        else {
            printf("That number is in the range\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Player 2, you have %d tries remaining\n", maxguesses);

    for (i = 0; i < maxguesses; i++) {
        printf("Enter your guess\n");
        scanf("%d", &guessing);

        if (enternumber == guessing) {
            printf("Player 2 wins.\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Too %s.\n", enternumber < guessing ? "high" : "low");
        }
    }
    return 0;

    if (count == maxguesses) {
        printf("Player 1 wins");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing can run after `return`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils where should i put it and what should be the correct code? i can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: All code below a return is "unreachable". I'd start by moving the return statement to be the last in main and see what that gets you.

Comment: i think i might have got it. i placed a while loop instead of if statement for the last part. while (guessing < maxguesses), i print it, break; then return statement at the last in main. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your return 0 statement after checking if count == maxguesses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define boolean

int main()
{

    int enternumber = -1;
    int count = 0;
    int maxguesses = 10;
    int guessing;
    int i;
    bool currentguesses = false;


    while (1) {
        count += 1;
        printf("Player 1, enter a number between 1 and 1000\n");
        scanf("%d", &enternumber);

        if (enternumber > 1000) {
            printf("That number is out of range\n");
        }

        else {
            printf("That number is in the range\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Player 2, you have %d tries remaining\n", maxguesses);

    for (i = 0; i < maxguesses; i++) {
        printf("Enter your guess\n");
        scanf("%d", &guessing);

        if (enternumber == guessing) {
            printf("Player 2 wins.\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Too %s.\n", enternumber < guessing ? "high" : "low");
        }
    }


    if (count == maxguesses) {
        printf("Player 1 wins");
    }
    return 0;
}
```